# User prompt before running node server

Tags: node.js, batch-file

So I created a `.bat` file contaning this code

**.bat file contents**

```
E:
cd E:/Projects\path\to\node_project
node server.js COM7
```

it works properly, but how can I ask for a user input to pass the COM7 as an argument to run the node server?

What I need to do is that when I run the `.bat` file, it will ask the user first to enter the COM port and then run the server after.

Comment: Is it a must to add user input part in .bat file or is it ok to add that piece of code in your js file? If so you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt

Comment: You can remove the first line and change the second one to `CD /D "E:\Projects\path\to\node_project"`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to prompt a message and set CMD environment variables is `SET /P variable=[promptString]`

folowing your example:

```
E:
cd E:/Projects\path\to\node_project
set /p arguments=your prompt message here 
node server.js %arguments%
```

You can check the [docs](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) if you want to do more fancy stuff.